# Javascript: Variable breaking function

Tags: javascript

### Original content for context:

---

When ever I try to add `var text0 = document.getELementById("text0");` to the following script, it breaks (it works without the text0 variable definition) how can I fix this?

Script:

```
function extend0 ()
{
    var nav0 = document.getElementById("nav1");
    var text0 = document.getELementById("text0");
    {
        nav0.style.paddingBottom = ("100px");
        nav0.style.paddingLeft = ("100px");
        nav0.style.paddingRight = ("100px");
        text0.style.opacity = ("1");
    }
}
```

---

### Edit, after a few years:

Please be careful with your code and look out for syntaxical and spelling errors, this includes mis-casing, JavaScript is a case-sensitive language meaning it doesn't 'understand' if you use the wrong case. Ensure you look over your code for any errors, especially in new lines of code that you have just deployed, causing breakages.

Comment: @Rejesh what do you mean by that?

Comment: Check the spelling of that line: it’s wrong.

Comment: @Xufox thanks! fixing the L worked.

Comment: @Rajesh what's wrong with doing that? I always do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript method names are case-sensitive. You're calling `getELementById`, not `getElementById` (with a lower-case L).

Comment: Questions that are based on typos should never be answered, but flagged or closed as off-topic, because such questions should be deleted.